# Laravel-PHP google drive API. Using different account to upload and share it throughout the site

Tags: php, android, google-drive-api, laravel-5.3

I am making a web and mobile application that lets you upload files through google drive. the thing is my storage is getting low, somebody told me that i should find a way to upload files depending on the user, it means every user should upload files through their own google drive account and can access it or get a shareable link so the storage consumption would not be crowded with different kind of files. is there a way to do that, if not is there any other cloud storage that provides that kind of concept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Speaking of Google, I know that Firebase has a [cloud-based file storage system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) embeded to its database solution (or might be used independently).

Comment: does firebase have their own auth features? if yes can it be replaced by my own auth?

Comment: I know they provide `firebase\jwt-php` but not sure if this is shipped with a sort of packages or something..

Answer (score 0):

For application specific data, you may want to check [Storing Application Data](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder). The Google Drive API includes a special hidden folder that your app can use to store application specific data.

As discussed in the given documentation,

> The App Folder is a special folder that is only accessible by your application. Its content is hidden from the user and from other apps. Despite being hidden from the user, **the App Folder is stored on the user's Drive and therefore uses the user's Drive storage quota.**

See if it will help you, otherwise you can use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/) or [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) as also suggested by Anwar Nairi. Both of these offer storage services which are ideal for your app. Drive API is meant for personal use.